# PyQt - QWebView Enables Application Cache?

Tags: python, pyqt, application-cache

I wonder how to enable `application cache` in a `Qt` program written in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code: 
Remember to change the `'__your_path__'` to a path you like to store the data.

```
settings = QWebSettings.globalSettings()
settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.OfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled, True)
settings.enablePersistentStorage('__your_path__')
```

If you only uses `OfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled`, it will only be of no use! Remember to use `enablePersistentStorage` also.